# Explanations for the Hilbert symbols

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

Are there some *elementary* sources which help me to understand the Hilbert symbol and the proof of the Hasse-Minkowski-theorem?

If you know anything which explains it well (except J.-P. Serre's book!) could you share it with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Serre's exposition is the best in my opinion and explains everything very well. If your problem is his treatment of the p-adics then I suggest you look at e.g. Gouvea for a more concrete description of them or that you take Theorems 3 and 4 in Serre's book in Chapter II as a black box. Especially from the Hilbert symbol onwards it is mainly computational. Incredible clever of course and not possible for a mortal to come up with but not too hard to follow. This is an intrinsically difficult theorem so it is not to be expected that there are truly "elementary" sources.

Answer (score 0):

Adam Gamzon's senior thesis [here](https://opencommons.uconn.edu/srhonors_theses/17/) proves the Hasse-Minkowski theorem over $\mathbf Q$ and $F(T)$ for finite fields $F$ of odd characteristic.  It has more examples than in Serre's account, and it approaches the Hilbert symbol in a different way: it proves the Hilbert symbol is bimultiplicative *before* working out a formula for the Hilbert symbol (in completions of $\mathbf Q$ other than $\mathbf Q_2$; the formula in the $2$-adic case is not needed in Gamzon's approach to the Hasse-Minkowski theorem).

You could also look at Tim Curry's senior thesis [here](https://production.wordpress.uconn.edu/alozano/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/Curry_Thesis_May_2014.pdf) for an account of the Hilbert symbol on completions of $\mathbf Q$ and $\mathbf Q(i)$. Here too, the bimultiplicativity of the symbol is proved before looking at formulas for it.